# Server hangs on "bringing up interface bond0"

Tags: bonding, rhel4

Server is HP DL380 running Red Hat 4.

Server is cloned by swapping drives in raid. When starting in new server, kudzu finds 4 nics removed, 4 nics added, and adds default ifcfg-eth0 - 4 in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

Then I basically tried to follow this procedure http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-bond-or-team-multiple-network-interfaces-nic-into-single-interface.html to bond the interfaces.

The server it is cloned from runs fine with bonded nics.

Anyone have a good idea of what might be wrong or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Are you trying to bond 4 nics? What is your ifcfg-eth0/1/2/3 configuration? What is your modprobe.conf like? Is the hardware of the source and clone servers the same?

Comment: A colleague here found the reason, but you were obviously on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a space after a = in the ifcfg-eth0-4 files.